# PuPHPet doesn't run custom script

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, puppet, puphpet

I played with this for far too long, (a week now) and I need some help.

I created a Vagrant config with [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com) and it gives me a lot of errors.
The simple thing what I'm trying is to run a 12.04 Ubuntu with Nginx, PHP and MySQL.

My problem comes when I add a custom script to the `puphpet/files/exec-always`, called `provision.sh` as the original documentation writes:

> You can run your own custom code after the VM finishes provisioning by adding files to the puphpet/files/exec-always and puphpet/files/exec-once folders.

The following small script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /project/app

# Run migrations
echo ">> Running migrations"
php ./yiic migrate --interactive=0
```

My `config.yaml` can [be found here](http://pastebin.com/iCAHy7Pw).

The whole output can [be found here](http://pastebin.com/p1AfuhmV).

So I have a clean, PuPHPet generated file structure. What are these errors and why is my script not executed?

**And one more thing**: My MySQL user, doesn't get the `ALL PRIVILEGES` right, phpmyadmin only writes: *USAGE*. If someone could help with this also, would be more then nice ;)

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution to this in the end? I have the same issue at the moment. My scripts in exec-always never run

Comment: Hi @Gortron, sorry but I couldn't figure it out back then and we decided to drop Vagrant because of the lot of problems. Instead we created our own VM image that we copied.

Comment: Hi @Edifice. OK cool, thank you for getting back to me.

Comment: I am also unable to run any scripts. Well its running the scripts but there is something funky going on. It says it can't find some files in /etc that are there.

Answer (score 1):

In the directories `exec-once/exec-always/..` there are files called empty.

That file should be removed for the directory that contains your script, in this case the `puphpet/files/exec-always` directory.

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with scripts not running. The files named "empty" are just there so that the folders (if truly empty) can be pushed to a version control system